# What is the speed and detail operation when several devices do a Speedtest in an MU-MIMO router simultaneously?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, bandwidth, speed

I have read a lot of articles that try to explain how MU-MIMO works, but I still can't figure out how the below picture works. It shows that MU-MIMO Wi-Fi allows every device to have an ISP speed while they connected to wifi simultaneously, so how is it possible to give the maximum bandwidth to the three devices? Is it the actual happen when I do it by Speedtest?

I know MU-MIMO technology is to reduce the delay of communicating to several devices simultaneously, but when the router receives the packages, it still needs to send the packages one by one, so what is the significance of this operation? Can someone clearly explain the actual flow and the bandwidth calculation steps when three devices do a Speedtest in an MU-MIMO router theoretically? Thank you.

[image: mu-mimo-speed-explain]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That picture is a either a blatant misrepresentation or is plain wrong.

The first side of the image should show the speeds being dependent on distance and interference and obstructions. The closest device may get 50-100Mbps (or the full 100Mbps) and speed drops as distance and other factors come into play.

The second image *should* be implying that each device *can* achieve the full 100Mbps available if they are the only device using it at that moment, not that they can all get a full 100Mbps *each at the same time*. MIMO would allow each device to get a stable 100Mbps connection to all devices, not to magically increase your internet speed.

You cannot split 100Mbps into 3 x 100Mbps *simultaneously*. you would need a 300Mbps connection to do that.